# iOS: Fix/lock Camera View in Portrait Mode/Orientation

Tags: ios, xcode, camera, orientation, portrait

I'd like to fix my Camera View in Portrait Mode but I found NO solution till now...

Do YOU have one? Would make my day .__.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot explicitly restrict the UIImagePickerController to portrait mode, but you can customize the look of the camera's user interface, which may help you. This is the example code from Apple:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoPicker/Introduction/Intro.html

Another method of controlling the camera's look is mentioned in this question:

[Camera with Custom View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7639188/ios-camera-with-custom-view)

I don't know exactly what your goal is, but one of these methods should help.

Comment: I have a custom CameraViewOverlay, which I cannot remove from screen, when I took the image and got directed to the preview. If I could fix the Camera View to Portrait Mode, the image would not turn in preview. Otherwise the Overlay is in wrong position ond the preiew image..

Comment: What do you mean by "directed to the preview"? Maybe you post a screenshot of what is happening.

Comment: The Preview View follows directly after you took the picture. Look at this example: http://www.iphonedevelopers.com/files/2010/03/iphone-photo.png

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean. I just tried it out. Apparently you can only look at the preview in portrait mode. There's nothing in the documentation about locking the Camera orientation, so you'll probably have to live with it unless you want to make a custom interface. Unless it really bothers you, it's probably not worth it.