# How to get a picture same as viewfinder UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, iphone, image, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

I am using UIIMagePickerController to take image using camera on iOS, I want to know how is it possible to capture the picture same as shown in the viewfinder which is full screen in this case. What will be the resolution ? Can it be high enough ?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

when you use UIImagePickerController controller you can get only the default resolution images as per your device camera resolution. If you want to customize your camera screen you can use AVCamCaptureManager. Please refer this link for more info : [Camera with Custom View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7639188/ios-camera-with-custom-view)