# How to keep camera in capture mode after taking a photo or video?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, avcapturesession

I want my camera to remain in capture mode even after a photo is clicked and saved (something that we see in Whatsapp's camera). Is there any way to implement this using UIImagePickerController?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/8101616/5362916

Comment: Your question is too broad. What have you tried ? Are u using avfoundation or camera picker ?

Comment: I know that there's a way to do this using AVFoundation as well but currently I am using camera picker right now